# how to auto control the height of image<img> inside link<a> in css

Tags: html, css, height

I have an html css code in

https://jsfiddle.net/zakutrp4/

the output style above `<div style='height:1em'></div>` line is what I want

for some reason I need to add link`<a></a>` outside the `<img>` but the output style below `<div style='height:1em'></div>` is not what I want. I want the output style is like that above `<div style='height:1em'></div>`. I want to know how to change the source code? Maybe add some style in `<a>`. Can somebody figure out how to solve the problem?

soure code:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons'>

<nav style='display:grid; grid-auto-flow:column; justify-content:start; column-gap:1em; background-color:red; color:white; height:2em; align-items:center'>
    <strong style='display:grid; grid-auto-flow:column; justify-content:start'><span class='material-icons'>list</span>商品分类</strong>
    <img src='https://how2j.cn/tmall/img/site/chaoshi.png' style='height:100%'>
    <img src='https://how2j.cn/tmall/img/site/guoji.png' style='height:100%'>
    <a>平板电视</a>
    <a>电热水器</a>        
</nav>

<div style='height:1em'></div>

<nav style='display:grid; grid-auto-flow:column; justify-content:start; column-gap:1em; background-color:red; color:white; height:2em; align-items:center'>
    <strong style='display:grid; grid-auto-flow:column; justify-content:start'><span class='material-icons'>list</span>商品分类</strong>
    <a><img src='https://how2j.cn/tmall/img/site/chaoshi.png' style='height:100%'></a>
    <a><img src='https://how2j.cn/tmall/img/site/guoji.png' style='height:100%'></a>
    <a>平板电视</a>
    <a>电热水器</a>        
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<nav style='display:grid; grid-auto-flow:column; justify-content:start; column-gap:1em; background-color:red; color:white; height:2em; align-items:center'>
    <strong style='display:grid; grid-auto-flow:column; justify-content:start'><span class='material-icons'>list</span>商品分类</strong>
    <a style='display:contents'><img src='https://how2j.cn/tmall/img/site/chaoshi.png' style='height:100%'></a>
    <a style='display:contents'><img src='https://how2j.cn/tmall/img/site/guoji.png' style='height:100%'></a>
    <a>平板电视</a>
    <a>电热水器</a>        
</nav>
```